# asp.net mvc editor template is not called and displaying text

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here is my method

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new Page();

        var content = new EditableContent { SidebarRight = "sss", SidebarLeft = "fff" };

        var content1 = new EditableContent { SidebarRight = "fff", SidebarLeft = "fggggg" };
        var Contents= new List<EditableContent>{ content , content1 };
        viewModel.Content = Contents;

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Here is my model

```
   public class EditableContent
{
    public string SidebarLeft { get; set; }
    public string SidebarRight { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public List<EditableContent> Content { get; set; }
}
```

here is my view `Index`

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.Page
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    @Html.EditorFor(page => page.Content, "Content")  
    <input type="submit" value="create" />
}
```

Here is my partial view `EditableContent`

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.EditableContent

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SidebarLeft)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SidebarRight)
```

now when i render the Index page it displayed sss , fff and it doesn't call the template code? what might be the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial needs to be created within the following folder structure `Views/EditorTemplates/EditableContent.cshtml`.

**Screen output**

[image: Screen output]

Comment: ok it works but strange i had the impression that it iterates by itself http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/ , i read one or two answers here as well

Comment: ok i miss creating it in editortemplates folder, but iterating is not required and that was the problem

Comment: @maz3tt Nice one, I updated the answer to reflect that. :)